# How do I equip my S.H.I.V?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I invested into S.H.I.V tech and I have a hover S.H.I.V and a alloy S.H.I.V ready in my barracks. However, I'm unable to edit the loadout of these units (everthing except "dismantle" is greyed out) and when I take one on a mission, it comes unarmed which makes it pretty useless except for scouting.

I read somewhere that it might be a bug that occurs when you lose a S.H.I.V in battle, which is exactly what happened to me.

So the question is: Is this a confirmed bug or is there anything I'm missing? And if it is a bug, is there *any* workaround? Can the save-game be edited to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The S.H.I.V is automatically equipped with the best weapon that you've researched for it, normal rifle at start, then laser, then plasma. If you've researched plasma before laser, you will get plasma and never have a laser S.H.I.V.

There is no way to manually equip the S.H.I.V, because if everything work right, you shouldn't have any need to equip it, as you don't need to manufacture each weapon, like with the laser and plasma rifles, but just make the upgrade at the foundry.

What you describe sounds like a bug, and you should report it to [2K support](http://support.2k.com/anonymous_requests/new)

Comment: You're right. I just researched plasma for the S.H.I.V and it fixed the "bug". So I just hopes it doesn't happen again, as there's probably no higher tech than plasma :). It looks like I'm not the only one with this issue: http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?152651-S-H-I-V-Unable-to-Deploy